# null out all references to a removed entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity Client and an entity Session.  Client has a field `currentSession` which references a Session entity.  At some point, I end up deleting sessions, sometimes this is the client's current session.  Is there any way that I can instruct my persistence provider to `null` the `currentSession` field of a client if it references the session that I'm removing?

```
@Entity
public class ClientEntity {

    @OneToOne
    private SessionEntity currentSession;
}
```

When I'm done with a certain session; I want to remove it like this.  Note that there is no guarantee that `session` is also the client's current session.

```
entityManager.remove( session );
```

I could do it all in code, but that would just be ugly; and I'd like to have the persistence provider take care of this relationship management for me.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand you are talking about what quite a lot of people miss in Hibernate, something like Cascade.SET_NULL. this has been discussed already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462898/jpa-not-generating-on-delete-set-null-fk-restrictions) and [there](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=946681&view=previous&sid=a292f0816e8d2bbc7dcf84327b8df596).

And as one of the posters advises, you'll need to do it by yourself in an interceptor or listener, or find another way around to achieve what you exactly need.

Comment: Would you be able to explain why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1012874/hibernate-unidirectional-parent-child-relationship-delete-performs-update-on has hibernate setting something to null in response to deleting data?

Comment: You got me here - I have no idea. Most probably there's a part of the story we don't know. And even if it's possible to replicate, I really doubt that Hibernate will hunt all the POJOs that represent that particular data entry and will set the reference to null.